# Chrome adding inline css

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

I have a website with a sidebar, see following code snippet:

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <% if(Model.Count > 0){ %>
```

IE adds a margin-top: 0px (which causes the website to display properly), Chrome adds a margin-top: -676px. That margin-top is not defined in the belonging css.

I can´t figure out where that is coming from.

Can someone help?

Comment: Its probably coming from the the javascript code which is written for sidebar in your js file

Comment: check browser developer tool properly

Comment: if you want to remove the margin-top try `#sidebar{margin-top:0 !important}` in your css

Comment: If the website is live, could you share he URL?

Comment: Bhuwan, that helped me out!
Unfortunately (or fortunately ;) ) that revealed the *.js to be causing the problems. In IE the sidebar is moving when scrolling, in Chrome it is not.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't enough information to know where this margin is coming from, *however* Chrome's dev tools allow you to see where certain styles are coming from.

- Press CTRL+SHIFT+I to open the dev tools
- Press CTRL+SHIFT+C to enter element selector mode
- Click the element in question
- Refer to the screenshot below to find out where the margin is coming from

[image: chrome dev tools screenshot]

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Definitely helpful, but in that specific css it lists margin: 0.

I think I found a belonging part in the sidebar.js, but I wonder why IE renders the page as it should and Chrome does not.